How can I see how many bytes does bucket versioning take in an S3 bucket?
How can I see how many bytes does bucket versioning take in an  S3 bucket?
I tried:
aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive s3://my-bucket/

but it doesn't show the bucket versioning size.

You can use list-object-versions — AWS CLI Command Reference to view 'versions' of objects in a bucket:
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket my-bucket
The response will include a Size for each versioned object. The response is in JSON, so you can use --query to obtain a simpler result page. It would be something like (and I didn't test this):
  aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket my-bucket --query 'Versions[].[Key,Size]' --output text

